# Xdebug profiler only working on localhost

Tags: php, zend-framework, xdebug

I'm trying to get to grips with xdebug profiler on osx. I have it set up, but it's only working on localhost. i.e http://localhost/foo/bar.php

I have a Zend Framework app on a vhost, but no profile data is being collected from it.

My php.ini looks like :

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.remote_enable= On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 999
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 99999
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 100

xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
```

Comment: Is your Vhost on the same machine (localhost) or on a remote machine?

Comment: Yea - seemed to be some weird php.ini caching issue. When I printed my phpinfo from the vhost it wasn't picking up the changes to the php.ini - even after an apache full stop and start. A restart did the trick. Odd!

Comment: So still having the same problem or not?

Answer (score 1):

Xdebug does whatever php.ini tells it to do. If there is no configuration, Xdebug won't profile. It doesn't care which VHOST it is. So it's likely that you had a configuration issue.